# Come up with a real inner product space $V$ and $T\in \mathcal L(V) $ and real numbers b, c with $ b^2 < 4c $ so that $T^2 + bT +cI$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, problem-solving

I've been self studying Linear Algerba Done Right, and I have had past exposure to linear algebra( college level), although it wasn't proof based.
I am struggling with this exercise:
Exercise [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKJRt.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKJRt.png

this is the solution proposed by Axler[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwlx0.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwlx0.png

My attempt was this:

Define a linear map $T$ with respect to the standard basis in $\Re^3$ which has the matrix :

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

(notice the matrix is not equal to its traspose, $T^*$) then proceed to compute the result of $$T^2 +bT +cI$$( choosing $b=1=c$) , yet the result is invertible.
Should I have chosen an operator which wasn't invertible from the start(i.e. non injective or surjective)?, or is it the choice of $b,c$? I thought that the operator not being self adjoint would guarantee the result together with a choice of b,c which respected the inequality.

Furthermore,what is the thought process of coming up with a rotation to solve the problem, or more generally, a map that allows us to solve this?

Comment: Let $r=\sqrt{c-b^2/4}.$ Then $$T^2+bT +cI=(T+(b/2)I)^2+ r^2=r^2\{[ r^{-1}(T+(b/2)I)]^2+I\}$$ We can substitute $$U=r^{-1}(T+(b/2)I)$$Hence it suffices to consider the matrix $U$ such that $U^2+I$ is not invertible.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc : Why not make this an answer? It looks better for the site if questions are answered, and marked as such.